# i18n load partially in locale app

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Django (es) translation file in my custom app is loading partially, because:

- The variables that are new in my app (but not in django folder) are translated.
- The variables that are by default in django and also in my app(I want to change the default translation) are not translated.

My code:

in django default locale folder:

```
msgid "Log in"
msgstr "Iniciar sesión"
```

In my app locale folder:

```
msgid "Log in"
msgstr "bla bla bla"
```

**NOT TRANSLATED**   I see the "Iniciar sesión"  values and not "bla bla bla"

```
msgid "This is my site of bla bla bla"
msgstr "Esta es mi web de bla bla bla"
```

**This is working fine**

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your files. If you are using i18n for English and Spanish for example you can do something like:

```
 django-admin.py makemessages -l es
 django-admin.py makemessages -l en
 django-admin.py compilemessages
```

You need to setup your settings correctly with your locale folder as well.

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)
```

And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) is explained the order that locale translations are loaded.

Comment: Thanks for answer me. I have already compile files in the same way you are saying me. I have added LOCALE_PATH but the problem persist. I think the file is loaded fine, but the access for a variable that is translated in django default folders don't work properly.

Comment: Maybe we need more information to understand what is happening, because this should not happen. Here is where explains the preference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem. It was the order of the INCLUDED_PATHS.

Comment: @JuanDiegoGonzalez Can you explain in detail about your solution?